# Mutual information between continuous $Z$ and $g(Z)$ for differentiable $g$?

Tags: continuous-data, entropy, mutual-information

I have a continuous random variable $Z$ and a differentiable function $X = g(Z)$. Is the mutual information between $X$ and $Z$ necessarily $\infty$ or 0? Are there any examples of differentiable functions where the differential entropy $h(Z \mid X)$ is not either $h(Z)$ or diverging?